# How to tell oak from walnut flooring

Tags: flooring, hardwood-floor, hardwood-refinishing

How do I identify what kind of hardwood flooring this is by the grain?

[image]

Comment: that is not walnut and almost surely oak.   Walnut grains are way way more subtle and wavy.

Comment: 99% certain that's oak. Are you doing a patch job or a repair? If so then you'll need to figure out whether it's red or white oak.

Comment: Something to think about: Identifying wood from a picture is difficult enough that it's considered off-topic at [woodworking.se].

Comment: For what it’s worth, the diagonal ray fleck is classic quartersawn oak. (Ray fleck occurs in other species, though usually to a lesser degree.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oak - more lines (harsh), texture, example

[image]

Walnut - several species are used but the have more of a wavy, "rock hit water" texture.

Black walnut

[image]

Traditional American

[image]

Comment: For solid hardwood, oak is by far the most common in the US.  Engineered hardwood has more variety since only a sliver of wood is needed - many more varieties become affordable.